# BASH: how to silently invoke the external script passing the variables to 'case'

Tags: bash, shell

the situation is as follows: i have Global script with Interactive TUI and several functions, and intermediate script, that must use only 1 function from the global script.
Ex:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "   INSTRUCTIONS:"
read -rsp $'Press any key to continue...          \n' -n1 key

function1 {
}

function2 {
}

function3 {
}

read -r -p "Let's go? [yes/no]: " input
    if [[ "$input" != "yes" ]]
        then  
            echo "Process aborted." && 
            exit
    fi

PS3='(hit the number): '
OPT=("1" "2" "3")
select opt in "${OPT[@]}"
do
    case $opt in "1")
        function1
        break
        ;;

        "2")
        function2
        break
        ;;

        "3")
        function3
        break
        ;;

        *) 
        echo invalid option, please retry 
        ;;

    esac
done
exit 0
```

The question is how to provide the arguments to the Intermediate script the way it will silently use 'function3' only, without getting prompted to do anything Global script does? (read prompts and select choice)

Comment: Have the script check whether `$1` is set, and use that instead of prompting.

Comment: @Barmar: Can you please give an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the option as a command-line argument, and skip the prompt if it's set. To avoid repeating the `case` code, put it into a function so it can be called from the main-line code and the `select` loop.

```
#!/bin/bash

function1() {
}

function2() {
}

function3() {
}

do_func() {
    opt=$1
    case $opt in 
        "1")
        function1
        ;;

        "2")
        function2
        ;;

        "3")
        function3
        ;;

        *) 
        echo invalid option, please retry 
        ;;

    esac
}

if [ -n "$1" ]
then
    do_func "$1"
    exit 0
fi

echo "   INSTRUCTIONS:"
read -rsp $'Press any key to continue...          \n' -n1 key

read -r -p "Let's go? [yes/no]: " input
    if [[ "$input" != "yes" ]]
        then  
            echo "Process aborted." && 
            exit
    fi

PS3='(hit the number): '
OPT=("1" "2" "3")
select opt in "${OPT[@]}"
do
    do_func "$opt"
done
exit 0
```

You would then use:

```
scriptname 3
```

to run `function3`.

Comment: thank you, @Barmar, will try that. And how to invoke this function3 from the external script, silently bypassing all  the prompts, including 'read' in the beginning?

Comment: Added that to the answer.

Comment: Thanks, @Barmar. This is it!